# glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor()) not working

Tags: java, lwjgl, bytebuffer

So i was watching a tutorial for java on how to create a window using Lwjgl and i got to this part where you get the primary monitor:

```
    ByteBuffer vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());

    glfwSetWindowPos(
            window,
            (GLFWVidMode.width(vidmode) - width) / 2,
            (GLFWVidMode.height(vidmode) - height) / 2
        );
```

However i get this error on eclipse : "Type mismatch: cannot convert from GLFWVidMode to ByteBuffer"

which results in this not being allowed:
GLFWVidMode.width
GLFWVidMode.height (it says: "The method height() in the type GLFWVidMode is not applicable for the arguments (ByteBuffer)")

I have searched for another tutorial and it also uses the methods in that order so I'm not sure what should i replace for it to work or if they updated something in Lwjgl 3.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Never mind, i checked the source site and it appears that in fact they changed it so it's now this:

```
GLFWVidMode vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());

    glfwSetWindowPos(
            window,
             (vidmode.width() - width) / 2,
            (vidmode.height() - height) / 2
        );
```

Comment: Same as @fractal5 I ran into this problem when looking at an outdated tutorial. I just want to add that this solution is found at https://www.lwjgl.org/guide below the setup guide.